# Proving Vectors Inside a Subspace Satisfy Given Condition

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a proof style question regarding vectors and orthonormal bases. It is as follows:

Let *V1* and *V2* be an orthonormal basis for W which is a subset of R^n. Prove that if *w* is a vector in W then the following holds:

||*w*||^2 = (*w* . *V1*)^2 + (*w* . *V2*)^2

I have tried a few things here however the first thing I noticed was this provided condition looks very similar to the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality but was not really sure how that is relevant.

One of the things I have tried was breaking down each part of the equation. I thought if *w* is inside W which is an orthonormal basis it would have a length of 1 so the left hand side of the equation would be equal to 1 but then I got stuck as I know when orthogonal vectors are dotted against each other their dot product is 0 which would mean the left hand side would be 0 + 0 which is obviously not equal to 1.

I have in my notes all the properties of vector dot products as well as those of orthonormal bases but cannot seem to organise those in such a way that explains the given condition.

Thank you for any feedback or advice.

Comment: Your notation $w \cdot v_1$ and $w \cdot v_2$ seem to indicate that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are vectors. But for $(v_1, v_2)$ to be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you then need $n = 2$. Is this right?

Comment: @michael I am sorry.. I could not understand the notation you have used here.. What do you mean by $w.V_1$ where $V_1$ is an orthonormal basis(it is a set of vectors know!!!)? By this expression what you are trying to tell about the innerproduct?

Comment: Sorry yes v1 and v2 and both vectors but these are also the orthogonal basis. Also I'm not sure why n isn't specified as n=2 but thanks definitely enough here for me to think about to get closer to understanding this

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(v_1, \dotsc, v_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we can write $w$ as a (unique) linear combination $w = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i$ and thus have
$$
 w \cdot v_j
 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i \right) \cdot v_j
 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \underbrace{v_i \cdot v_j}_{\delta_{ij}}
 = \lambda_j
$$
for all $1 \leq j \leq n$, and therefore
$$
 \|w\|^2
= w \cdot w
= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i \right)
   \cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i \right)
= \sum_{i,j=1}^n \lambda_i \lambda_j \underbrace{v_i \cdot v_j}_{\delta_{ij}}
= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2
= \sum_{i=1}^n (w \cdot v_i)^2.
$$